# Combine array and object destructuring

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

How to destruct a value from array?

```
const ?? = { text: ['some text'] };
```

Comment: General advice for destructuring. If you're not sure how to destructure a particular value from an object literal, make the destructuring syntax _match_ the object literal. Though in this case, the assignment might be much easier to read as `const someText = object.text[0]` instead.

Answer (score 7):

```js
const { text: [someText]} = { text: ['some text'] };

console.log(someText);
```